# VS: Automatic "ArgumentNull' check?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, autocomplete, code-generation, resharper

It's often the case when I need to check a method's arguments for not being null, something like:

```
public static bool operator <= 
    (ApplicationVersion i_app1, ApplicationVersion i_app2)
{ 
    if (i_app1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("i_app1");
    if (i_app2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("i_app2");
    [...]
}
```

Is there a way to do this (semi)automatically, like Code snippets? Autocomplete? Resharper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper has this feature. If you have cursor over parameter name - say i_app1 and hit Alt-Enter - it offers the option to check for null.

Comment: It's hidden under the lightbulb icon that appears on your left once your cursor is on the parameter - in the method signature. Also what version of R# you use?

Comment: The "I'm blind" comment was intended as self-irony, i.e. the answer was right there under my nose and I failed to see it until you pointed me to it :).

Answer (score 2):

I have an extension method for this which at least makes it *slightly* simpler:

```
i_app1.ThrowIfNull("i_app1");
```

The implementation is simple:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T argument, string name)
    where T : class
{
    if (argument == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
```

I prefer this to using snippets or whatever, as it means the code itself is shorter. Typing is rarely an issue for me - whereas keeping the code as readable as possible is.

Hopefully [Code Contracts](http://microsoft.com/contracts) in .NET 4.0 will make this neater still though.

Comment: This type of extension method makes me shudder a bit. The only thing more disturbing is ByRef extension methods :).  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/12/11/extension-methods-and-byref-targets.aspx

Comment: @Jared: What do you dislike about it? It says what you intend to do incredibly simply. As for the "by ref" one - presumably that doesn't work in C#? I'd really hope not!

Comment: My gut reaction is to balk at a method that is called on a null reference. I realize it's an extension method and under the hood it becomes a static call so no issue.  But I still have a hard time getting over the initial gut reaction.

Comment: (cont) I personally prefer ThrowIfNull(i_app1, "i_app1") but that's not feasible in C# (works great in VB).  In C# i usually go for Argument.VerifyNotNull(i_app1,"i_app1") or go for a snippet.

Comment: (cont2) and yes, byref extension methods are not supported in C#.

Comment: I think it's a matter of just realising that it *does* support null references - I think I'd only use that fact for methods which are *explicitly* to do with null, e.g. this, IsNullOrEmpty etc.

Comment: @Jon, very true. I think i've been ruined because of several bits of C++ code I've worked with which have explicitly different behavior when an instance method is called with a NULL this.  No special method names, just "oh no problem, we support NULL in a weird way" type methods.

Comment: Interesting approach. However, I'm bound to .net 2.0, so I can't use extension methods :(

Comment: @Cristi, you can use extension methods in 2.0 app as long as you are using a C# 3.0 compiler (http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/11/16/extension-methods-without-3-5-framework.aspx)